# Сколько цифр в переменной?

Tags: javascript, utf, length

Есть такая задача - найди количество цифр в числе и записать результат в переменную quantity. Вот упрощенное задание

```js
var number = 123;
var quantity = 0;

var string = '123';

quantity1 = toString(number).length;
quantity2 = string.length;

console.log('quantity1 = ' + quantity1);
console.log('quantity2 = ' + quantity2)
```

У меня вопрос, почему конвертация цифрового представления переменной number при помощи toString дает неожиданный результат? (*Я надеялся что будет тоже 3) Я конечно, попробовал разобраться. по документации [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length), но увы не сошлось. Может кто-то объяснить ?

Comment: `console.log('toString(number) = "' + toString(number) + '"');`

Comment: `number.toString().length` или `("" + number).length` Может перепутали со `String(number).length`

Comment: toString() это метод, он должен быть применен к объекту, т.е. объект для него должен стать `this`. А для этого он вызывается через точку после имени объекта (number.toString()). Вот почему JS позволяет его вызывать просто так, с неопределенным this (который приводит к логичному результату, строке `[object Undefined]`) для меня загадка

Comment: @Mike скорее всего есть некий глобальный глобальный объект `Undefined` - именно это и выводится в консоль `[object Undefined]`

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, Более вероятно что `toString` вызванный без контекста, по-прежнему возвращает свой контекст (а он `undefined`). Попробуй в консоли `Object.prototype.toString.call(undefined)`

Comment: @yar85 не согласен. Если я объявлю свой объект и вызову его метод как функцию без контекста(точнее_без_точки) - я получу ошибку `ReferenceError`. Каким образом может быть вызван `toString` которого нет глобально!? То что упомянул @Mike(...загадка), действительно является загадкой. Возможно это какая-то ошибка движка, а возможно движок "приставляет"(иногда) что-то спереди когда не может понять идентификатора.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, У разных методов разная реализация, а речь здесь идет конкретно о `toString`. Точка - не имеет значения: например, в предыдущем комментарии вызов вообще через `call` - результат аналогичен. Так же аналогичен он при вызовах `toString.call()` или `window.toString.call()`, в глобальном контексте. О чем это говорит, разве о других методах или точке? Не улавливаю связи. По-моему, это говорит об использовании контекста вызова, и данное предположение все объясняет на 100%.

Comment: toString вызывается на глобальном объекте window, это можно проверить `toString === window.toString` // true

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko на `window` он выведет `[object Window]`, а тут undefined

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg да, именно так и есть. Очень интересное поведение, но тем не менее, это одна и та же функция.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что toString(number) возвращает [object Undefined] а это 18 символов.

```js
console.log(toString(123));
console.log(toString(123).length);
```

obj.toString() возвращает строку, представляющую объект https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Вы перепутали со String();

```js
console.log(String(123).length)
```